# Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -x^{2n} \ln x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Last month, I read a proof of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ that used the following integral:
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+y)(1+x^2y)} \, dx \, dy$$ It was in [August-September](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.07.642)'s issue of the American Mathematical Monthly. Anyway, I was able to follow most of  it upto the last step where he switches integral and summation.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 -x^{2n} \ln x\,dx$$

I think I grasp how uniform convergence of a series can allow you to switch infinite sums and integral signs. But from what I can see $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -x^{2n} \ln x$ doesn't uniformly converge on $[0,1]$. It may be uniformly convergent on $[0,k]$ if $k \in (0,1)$? Is that enough to justify the switch?

Alternatively, the partial sums are strictly increasing and bounded. But how do you prove they converge to the integral on the left side?

Edit:

Is there a theorem that says: if $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[a,b]$ and $f_n$ is uniformly bounded then, $\int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx \to \int_a^b f(x) \, dx$? Is the following a proper proof? I'm trying to avoid using Lebesgue Integrals as I haven't studied them.

Suppose that $\displaystyle \left| \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx - \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx \right| = \epsilon>0$.

Since $\displaystyle \int_0^k f(x)\, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^k f_n(x)\,dx$ by uniform convergence on $[0,k]$. It remains to show that if $k$ is chosen properly then $\displaystyle \left| \int_k^1 f(x)\,dx-\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_k^1 f_n(x)\,dx \right| < \epsilon$, a contradiction. $f_n$ being uniformly bounded implies

$$ \left| \int_k^1 f(x)\,dx - \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_k^1 f_n(x)\,dx \right| < (1-k)M$$

So let $1-\frac{\epsilon}{M}<k<1$ so that $(1-k)M < \epsilon$.

Comment: Please fix the title of your question.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: Note that you missed several $n$ in the exponents: $x^{2n}$.

Comment: Oops, I'll fix all of them

Comment: You might want to use Lebesgue's integral.

Comment: Oh, so that's what he meant by "monotone convergence theorem."  I was thinking of the elementary version. I haven't studied Lebesgue's integrals yet :/

Comment: What do you think of my suggested proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$\cal Theorem:$ If $\{f_n:X\rightarrow R\}_n$  converges to $f$ pointwise and $\{f_n\}_n, f$ be continuous and $f_{n+1}(x)\leq f_n(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $X\subset R$ be a compact set, then it converges uniformly.

I'm not sure, but I think this theorem can help you.

And also check the first chapter of Wlter Rudin's book it is named "Real and Complex Analysis".This is the theorem you asked for it(Theorem 1.34).

Comment: Unfortunately, the theorem you referred me to uses Lebesgue integrals, which I do not understand. But I did find the theorem I wanted. It's called "Arzela's Bounded Convergence Theorem." I read that it is a trivial result in using Lebesgue integrals but I found one "elementary" proof of it here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/lguth/acepabct.pdf I'm still hazy over the last step with splitting nodes and closed intervals. Thanks for the help though.